# Conditional aggregates

Tags: sql-server, aggregate-functions, conditional-statements

I have a table with the following fields:

```
AuthorID
BookTitle
PageNo
Key
Value
```

Where the primary key is a composite key consisting of: `AuthorID, BookTitle, PageNo, Key`

I need a query that would display all BookTitles for AuthorID="ABC", and value of key "Field1" From first page and value of "Field2" from last page.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT BookTitle
     , a.FieldFromFirstPage
     , [Value] As FieldFromLastPage
     , b.LastPage 
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN (SELECT BookTitle, [Value] As FieldFromFirstPage 
     FROM Table1
     WHERE [Key]='Field1'
       and PageNo=1
       and AuthorID='ABC') As a ON BookTitle=a.BookTitle
INNER JOIN (SELECT BookTitle, MAX(PageNo) As LastPage
      FROM Table1 
      WHERE AuthorID='ABC' 
      GROUP BY BookTitle
      HAVING MAX(PageNo)> 0) As b ON BookTitle=b.BookTitle AND PageNo=b.LastPage
WHERE [Key]='Field2' and AuthorID='ABC'
```

This works for me but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this using conditional aggregates or some other methods?

Comment: (Not sure, but this might be better asked on codereview.SE.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd question the table's design. There should be a table books with an AuthorID (Why is this alphanumeric? Hopefully you do not save the author's name as the ID!) and a table pages with a BookID as a reference.
But - never the less - this should work:

EDIT: Replaced first attempt as it did not work. Hope this time it's better, but it's difficult to test without data...

```
--Fetch only books of the given AuthorID
WITH bookCTE AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT AuthorID,BookTitle
    FROM Table1
    WHERE AuthorID='ABC'
)
SELECT bookCTE.BookTitle
      ,(
        SELECT TOP 1 t.Field1 
        FROM Table1 AS t
        WHERE t.AuthorID=bookCTE.AuthorID
          AND t.BookTitle=bookCTE.BookTitle 
          AND t.PageNo=1      
       ) AS FieldFromFirstPage
      ,LastPageNumber.*
      ,(
        SELECT TOP 1 t.Field2 
        FROM Table1 AS t
        WHERE t.AuthorID=bookCTE.AuthorID
          AND t.BookTitle=bookCTE.BookTitle 
          AND t.PageNo=LastPageNumber.LastPage      
       ) AS FieldFromLastPage
FROM bookCTE
--find the max page number                     
CROSS APPLY(SELECT MAX(x.PageNo) FROM Table1 AS x WHERE x.AuthorID=bookCTE.AuthorID AND x.BookTitle=bookCTE.BookTitle) AS LastPageNumber(LastPage)
```

Comment: Unfortunately table design is not to be changed. It is not up to me - I just write queries in this case

Comment: OK, bad luck then... Did you try the SELECT above? You only have to add your WHERE at the end

Comment: Shnugo, your query does a completely different thing, not even close to what mine is doing

Comment: Hi Elena, sorry about that... So I got something wrong. Maybe you want to post the CREATE TABLE statement and some rows how to fill it? I'll post an edited statement in some minutes...